# I get an error when deploying a simple app in app-engine connected to SQL cloud

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine-python

I am just trying to learn about google cloud, in order to start getting the certificates.  I have download from the official github repo from Google, the example python app which is this one: [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/cloudsql) I have just changed the app.yml as follow:

```
  
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
service: practica

handlers:
- url: /
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"

# [START gae_python_mysql_env]
env_variables:
    CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME: practica-final-297818:europe-west3:practica-sql
    CLOUDSQL_USER: root
    CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
# [END gae_python_mysql_env]
```

but when trying to acces to the app I get an error stating:
"Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

I have check the logs from the app and I get this logs, but honestly I get nothing out of it (probably because I am new to GCP or any other cloud....)

```
ispatch()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/dd89b7af809b5e76/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/dd89b7af809b5e76/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/h~practica-final-297818/practica:version-1-0-0.431541023169113748/main.py", line 66, in get
    db = connect_to_cloudsql()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/h~practica-final-297818/practica:version-1-0-0.431541023169113748/main.py", line 46, in connect_to_cloudsql
    passwd=CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/dd89b7af809b5e76/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.5/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/dd89b7af809b5e76/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.5/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2062, 'Cloud SQL socket open failed with error: No such file or directory')
```

this is what cloud SQL config

```
settings:
  activationPolicy: ALWAYS
  availabilityType: REGIONAL
  backupConfiguration:
    backupRetentionSettings:
      retainedBackups: 7
      retentionUnit: COUNT
    binaryLogEnabled: true
    enabled: true
    kind: sql#backupConfiguration
    location: eu
    startTime: 11:00
    transactionLogRetentionDays: 7
  dataDiskSizeGb: '100'
  dataDiskType: PD_SSD
  ipConfiguration:
    authorizedNetworks:
    - kind: sql#aclEntry
      name: practica
      value: 111.111.111.111
    ipv4Enabled: true
  kind: sql#settings
  locationPreference:
    kind: sql#locationPreference
    zone: europe-west3-b
  maintenanceWindow:
    day: 0
    hour: 0
    kind: sql#maintenanceWindow
  pricingPlan: PER_USE
  settingsVersion: '25'
  storageAutoResize: true
  storageAutoResizeLimit: '0'
  tier: db-f1-micro
state: RUNNABLE
```

Comment: 1) Your app.yml and example code look fine. This points to a Cloud SQL related issue. 2) Did you assign a public IP address to the Cloud SQL instance? 3) Did you assign Cloud SQL roles to your identity/service-account such as Cloud SQL Client? 4) Show your entire app.yml. Show the Cloud SQL configuration (mask the IP address, login and password types of information). Use this command: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/describe

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have assign a public ip and I do not remember anythong about assigning cloud sql roles in the documentation from google...maybe I missed it?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. Google had an outage earlier today. Can you try again and see the outage was the problem?

Comment: I did not  see your comment, just the update. What roles have you assigned to the app engine service-account? You need at least Cloud SQL Client.

Comment: I have been trying for a couple of days, so it is not related to the google outbreak. If that is the one ending in ```cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com``` I have admin, client, editor and reader from cloud sql permits

Comment: Please be precise with role names. I do not see anything wrong with your setup. Can you connect from your desktop to Cloud SQL using the MySQL client (you will need to whitelist your IP address)?

Comment: I can connect from my workbench app. I meant that the account ending in ```cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com``` has the Clous sql admin, cloud sql client, cloud sql editor, and cloud sql reader permissions or is it this one the account ```developer.gserviceaccount.com```?

Comment: The roles need to be assigned to this service account: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/service-account

Comment: hmmm that might be the issue but I do not have any service account ending in: ```appspot.gserviceaccount.com```

Comment: ok I added that account service and added the sql client permission and it worked! thanks!

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I upvoted your comment that led to solving the issue. I suggest that you post it as an answer (including some of the steps on this discussion) so OP could upvote and accept it as well.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem the issue was the App Engine service account did not have Cloud SQL roles attached.

The solution is to use the Google Cloud Console and add one of the Cloud SQL roles:

- Cloud SQL Client (recommended)
- Cloud SQL Editor
- Cloud SQL Admin